# How to check if a process name is in ListView?

Tags: c#

I'm making a Windows service in C#. It gets all names of running processes and then checks if the ListView1 of Form1 contains it. I use this code to get running processes names:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
```

But how can I access to ListView of Form1 and then check if that ListView contains the process name.

Comment: You cant use a Form in a Windows Service Application.

Comment: LINQ query select clause should help you.

Comment: Describe more about what you want

Comment: Since the code is so simple, why have the form application depend on a service for it? Why not just use `Process.GetProcesses()` as the data source for the list view and update it periodically?

Comment: The reason why I use service is because this is not a simple app. It is based on service. Well, it's difficult to explain here...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a listview which contains the process names, you can do something like this,

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
List<string> found = new List<string>();
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    if (listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(i => i.Text.Contains(process.ProcessName))){
        found.Add(process.ProcessName);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but the problem is my ListView1 is in another form, and I don't know how to access it?

Comment: pass it inside the constructor of form2

Comment: Okay, I'm new to C# here so I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Luis, please update your question and also up your curent code so that we can see your design model. After that, we can give you suggestions